# Getting an average count based on parameters from both the parent and child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If a `User` `has_many` `Items`. And items can be published by setting the `:published` attribute in items to `true`.

How do I get the **average number** of **published items**, **per user** that **created** an item?

I have a scope for items called `published`, so you can get all published items by writing:

```
@items = Item.published
@items = @user.items.published
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is:

```
   avg = Item.published.count.to_f / User.count
```

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
  @published_items = User.joins(:items).where('items.published = ?', true)
  avg = @published_items.count.to_f / @published_items.all(:select => 'distinct users.*').count
```

Or:

```
  avg = Item.published.count.to_f / User.joins(:items).where('items.published = ?', true).all(:select => 'distinct users.*').count
```

Comment: I honestly didn't think of that... :). How would I change it so that it only counts the users who created an item? Thanks

Comment: `User` who created `published => true` item  or `User` has some `Items`??

Comment: User who created published => true. Thanks